# Algorithm that always returns the same pseudorandom output if given the same input of seed, x and y?

Tags: 2d, random

I've been trying to find an algorithm that will take in an *x* value, a *y* value, and a *seed* value and then spit out a number between 0 and 255 (or an int that I can cut up into bytes). I want to be able to feed in the tile a player is standing on during some ingame event and get the same value for the same tile any time the player is in that level. I don't want to use a linear PRNG because I just want to check a few tiles at any one time, not go though several of them to get a sequence.

I tried modifying an Xor Shift PRNG, but I just end up making patterns like below:

[image: pattern]

```
ubyte Xor( int wx, int wy, ulong seed ){
    int result = wx ^ (wx >> 7) ^ wy ^ (wy >> 9) ^ seed ^ (seed << 6);
    return cast(ubyte)result;
}
```

My input values are likely to be 0-32000 for x and y, and seed can be any ulong value. I'd like to avoid floating point math as it's not deterministic between machines (so it would screw up some multiplayer stuff). I just need to not get a repeating pattern, and have each seed produce a distinctly different output. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Basically, you want a hash value, is that it?

Comment: Maybe this question belongs more to http://math.stackexchange.com/...

Comment: Could you use 2D Perlin or Simplex noise?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I don't think math stackexchange is the right platform for this. This is obviously a programming problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a hash algorithm.  You'd concatenate your 16 bit x and y position into a 32 bit number and then hash that to get what is effectively a pseudo random number out.  The size of the hash output depends on what algorithm you use, but you could easily just use the lowest 8 bits of whatever the output is to get your 0-255 value.  It will have the properties that you want: neighboring tiles will usually have very different values, but the same tile will always give you the same result.  For use in a game scenario I would recommend murmurhash. Its not quite cryptographic quality, which is fine for your usage case, and is very fast while giving very nice pseudo random distribution (avalanche effect).

Murmurhash3 source code can be found here:  https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/source/browse/trunk/MurmurHash3.cpp

(:

Comment: Take a look at https://gist.github.com/badboy/6267743#64-bit-to-32-bit-hash-functions, which will specifically turn a 64 bit value (i.e. 16bit x + 16bit y + 32bit seed) into a 32bit hash value very fast (tens of machine instructions) and with minimal artifacts.

Comment: Great point about getting a seed in there BTW. With a seed you can make it different each run despite it doing what the op wanted (or however else you want to use the seed).

Answer (score 0):

Why not a PRNG, actually? It looks like a simple and good tool to me.

Some pseudocode using `srand`/`rand` that you should be able to adapt to any other PRNG:

```
int shuffle(int seed, int x, int y)
{
    int tmp;
    srand(seed); tmp = rand();
    srand(tmp + x); tmp = rand();
    srand(tmp + y); tmp = rand();
    return tmp;
}
```

This can actually be very fast. Using one of C++’s standard PRNGs, the following function compiles to just shuffling instructions (no std library calls) and can execute 80 million times a second (5 times faster than Murmurhash).

```
#include <random>

int shuffle(int seed, int x, int y)
{
    std::minstd_rand r;
    r.seed(seed); r.seed(r() + x); r.seed(r() + y);
    return r();
}
```